# Problem with calculating the mutual information

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Knowing that $Z = f(X)$ (i.e. $Z$ and $X$ have a deterministic relation), how can we calculate the quantity

$I (Y ;X,Z)$?

I come up with the following relation but then don't know how to proceed any further.

$I (Y ;X,Z) = I(Y;X) + I(Y; Z|X)$.

I know that $H(Z|X)=0$, but I don't know what it means for the above relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z=f(X)$ is a one-to-one (Injective) function of $X$, then $H(Z|X)=0$ as you mentioned above. In other words, knowing $X$ makes us capable of knowing $Z$ precisely. For example if $Z=X^2$ then knowing $X\in\{-1,1\}$ gives $Z=1$ and thus $H(Z|X)=0$, but knowing $Z=1$ means $X\in\{-1,1\}$ and thus $H(X|Z)\neq 0$.

Now we use the conditioning expansion as you mentioned above

$$I (Y ;X,Z) = I(Y;X) + I(Y; Z|X)$$

Also $I(Y; Z|X)=H(Z|X)-H(Z|Y,X)=0-0=0$ (definition of mutual information). Thus $I (Y ;X,Z) = I(Y;X)$, in other words, $Z$ is redundant data, useless.

About the mutual information, we have $I(Y;Z) = H(Z)-H(Z|Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|Z)$. For the conditional case the definition becomes 
$$I(Y;Z|X) = H(Z|X)-H(Z|Y,X)=H(Y|X)-H(Y|Z,X)$$

Comment: I don't understand where  $I(Y;Z|X)=H(Z|X)−H(Z|Y,X)$ comes from. Could you please elaborate? I know what $I(X;Y) = H(X)-H(X|Y)$.

Comment: I edited the answer to give the definition, if it's not satisfactory, we can go to the P.D.F. definition, but at some point you have to accept the definition of mutual information, the amount of uncertainty in $Z$ that reduces when you know $Y$ for $I(Y;Z)$ which is a symmetric quantity.